# json Unexpected token o in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am getting this type of error Unexpected token o in JSON 
error detials:

[object Object]

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

```
function address_transaction(address,callback)
{
var api_key='11111111111111'; 
var type='na';  
var url='some url';

var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {    
    var new1 =JSON.parse({"address":address,"response":response});
    callback(new1);  
  }
  else {
    console.log("Error "+response.statusCode)
  }
})
}
```

Comment: Try without `JSON.parse`

Comment: It is already JSON don't use parse method. JSON.parse() is used to convert string to JSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the important thing you need to know in nodejs is first parameter is an error so when you get an error so need to handle this like callback(err). if you get a result then return this result like this `callback(null, result)`

```
function address_transaction(address, callback) {
    var api_key = '11111111111111';
    var type = 'na';
    var url = 'some url';

    var request = require('request');
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var new1 = Object.assign({}, {
                        "address": address,
                        "response": response
                    };
                })
            callback(null, new1);
        } else {
            console.log("Error " + response.statusCode)
            callback(err)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant not parse `JSON.parse({"address":address,"response":response});`
you have to stringify first

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `JSON.parse`:

```
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {    
    var new1 =JSON.parse({"address":address,"response":response});
    callback(new1);  
  }
```

You are trying to convert your JSON to object when you already have an object and you cannot do this.

send your data like this:

```
var new1 = {"address":address,"response":response};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. JSON.parse({"address":address,"response":response}); is wrong because JSON.parse(...paramString) requires a string as parameter not an object per  your code.
2. {"address":address,"response":response}; is already a valid JSON object so you do not need to do any further parsin.

Removing JSON.parse should fix your issue:

```
var new1 = {"address":address,"response":response};
```

I suggest you to review the functions [JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify()](https://alligator.io/js/json-parse-stringify/) check it out